# Why am I not able to connect to minikube through Lens?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am using windows OS. Why is my minikube cluster not running?

I am getting the error message as:

**E0223 10:34:23.330057 10852 proxy_server.go:147] Error while proxying request: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:57040: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it**

Answer (score 0):

1. To check if minikube is running you can run command:

   minikube status
2. To be able to work with Minikube (installed and launched locally), you need to choose "Personal Space" account in accounts list of Lens.